# Managing hourly data into monthly data for the whole year Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

#### Background

The data [links](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7FE0kxAL8kQR0twLUZMaE1WajA) which I uploaded is the time series data of the con for the whole year at a monitoring station. The format of the data is shown like this:

[image]

#### My target

To investigate the temporal pattern of the samples, I want to plot the variation of the monthly sample.

Like the figure below which I downloaded from plot.ly. Each box represent the daily average sample of the raw data. And the monthly average values are outlined by the lines.

[image]

With `groupby` function or `pd.pivot` function, I can get the subset of certain month or daily data easily.

But I found out that it's hard to generate `a bunch of dataframes`.  Each one should contains the daily average data for certain month.

By pre-defining 12 empty dataframes, I can generate 12 dataframes which feed my need.  **But is there any neat way to divide the original dataframe and then generate multliple dataframes by user-defined conditions.**

#### EDIT

Inspired by the answer of @alexis. I tried to achieve my target with these code. And it works for me.

```
## PM is the original dataset with date, hour, and values.
position  = np.arange(1,13,1)
monthDict = {1:'Jan', 2:'Feb', 3:'Mar', 4:'Apr', 5:'May', 6:'Jun', 
            7:'Jul', 8:'Aug', 9:'Sep', 10:'Oct', 11:'Nov', 12:'Dec'}
pm['label'] = np.nan

for i in range(0,len(pm),1):
    pm['label'].iloc[i] = monthDict.get(int(pm['date'].str[4:6].iloc[i])) 

## Create an empty dataframe for containing the daily mean value.
df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=np.arange(0,31,1), columns=['A'])
for i,t in enumerate(pm.label.unique()):
    df[str(t)] = np.nan
df = df.drop(['A'],1)    

mean_ = []
for i in range(0,len(pm.label.unique()),1):
    month_data = pm.groupby(['label']).get_group(pm.label.unique()[i]).groupby(pm['date'].str[6:8])['pm25'].mean()
    mean_.append(month_data.mean())
    for j in range(0,len(month_data),1):
        df[pm.label.unique()[i]].iloc[j] = month_data[j]

#### PLOT 
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
ax = plt.subplot()
bp  = ax.boxplot( df.dropna().values, patch_artist=True, showfliers=False)
mo_me = plt.plot(position,mean_, marker = 'o', color ='k',markersize =6, label = 'Monthly Mean', lw = 1.5,zorder =3)

cs = ['#9BC4E1','k']
for box in bp['boxes']:
    box.set(color = 'b', alpha = 1)
    box.set(facecolor = cs[0], alpha = 1)
for whisker in bp['whiskers']:
    whisker.set(color=cs[1], linewidth=1,linestyle = '-')    
for cap in bp['caps']:
    cap.set(color=cs[1], linewidth=1)   
for median in bp['medians']:
    median.set(color=cs[1], linewidth=1.5)

ax.set_xticklabels(pm.label.unique(), fontsize = 14)    
# ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks(), fontsize = 12)
for label in ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels()[::2]:
    label.set_visible(False)   
for tick in ax.yaxis.get_major_ticks():
    tick.label.set_fontsize(14) 


plt.ylabel('Concentration', fontsize = 16, labelpad =14)    
plt.xlabel('Month', fontsize = 16, labelpad =14)    
plt.legend(fontsize = 14, frameon = False)
ax.set_ylim(0.0, 178)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

And this is my output figure.

[image]

> Any suggestion about my code on data management or visualization would be appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

Don't generate 12 dataframes. Instead of splitting your data into multiple similar variables, add a column that indicates which group each row should belong to. This is standard practice (with good reason) for database tables, dataframes, etc.

Use `groupby` on your dataset to group the data by month, then use `apply()` on the resulting `DataFrameGroupBy` object to restrict whatever analysis you want (e.g., the average to each group. This will also make it easy to plot the monthly results together.

You don't provide any code, so it's hard to be more specific than that. Show how you group your data by month and what you want to do to the monthly dataframes, and I'll show you how to restrict it to each month via the groupby object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Inspired by your suggestion, I have tried to do some works on the stuff. It would be great if you offer me some advice!

Comment: Glad you got it working. I can't offer any specific suggestions just from glancing at this much code, but it does give me the impression that you're probably using iteration to do things that `pandas` can do with its aggregate and grouping functions. I really can't say more, but you could take your code to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.  Its purpose is precisely to get advice on how to improve working code.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!